# Pretending a package has been loaded

Tags: packages, incompatibility, imakeidx, xpatch

I am trying to use `imakeidx` and the `regexpatch` package in the same class. Since `imakeidx` depends on the `xpatch` package and `xpatch` provides the same commands (same names, improved implementation) as regexpatch this gives errors (redefining commands). Is there anyway to pretend I loaded the `xpatch` package, so the `require` inside `imakeidx` won"t load anything? (Since I load `regexpatch` before, everything should be fine).

While I have a concrete example above, I would be interested in the general answer to prevent `require` statements from loading packages, a workaround for my particular case is a bonus (I guess either I am doing something wrong or the package author will take a look).

Comment: @egreg I think you might be the author of both packages, so I wanted to notify you. On page 17 line 37 of the `imakeidx` manual, it seems like you `\RequirePackage{xpatch}` unconditionally.

Comment: `\ProvidesFile{wibble.sty}` will make latex think that the `wibble` package has been loaded.

Comment: ...or `\makeatletter\let\ver@wibble\@empty\makeatother` (I think).

Comment: @Werner  \csname ver@wibble.sty\endcsname (so that wibble class and wibble package can both exist

Comment: @ted FYI, trying to notify someone the way you did with egreg doesn't work unless egreg is the author of the post, or if he/she has written a comment. If as you type the name it starts to auto-complete, the person will be notified, if it doesn't autocomplete, the person won't. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123594/make-invalid-user-comments-fail-more-explicitly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One can use David's suggestion, but `etoolbox` must be loaded anyway:

```
\ProvidesFile{xpatch.sty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
```

should do.

Answer (score 20):

egreg answered the specific issue but the general issue of avoiding package loading as mentioned in comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ProvidesFile{longtable.sty}

\usepackage{longtable}

\typeout{longtable is: \meaning\longtable}

\stop
```

produces

```
longtable is: undefined
```

showing that the package is not loaded, despite the `\usepackage`.